# excel file while reading it through javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, activex

I know this types of question doesn't belong to here but this is my last hope to get answer and solution for this. I had made a html and javascript program to read excel file through Active X, but problem is that whenever I run that page the it runs fine but when i closed it the excel file remain open and if I run this page 100 times and then close it then there will be 100 unclosed excel file which leads to slowdown my PC. And second problem is that when I try to open that excel file which is being used by that application(the application is not currently running when i tried to open excel file) it does not open without giving an error,an window of excel file open and closed with in a small part of second..I don't know what to do  to resolve this. If there is any problem in my code then here it is

```
    var xVal = 1;
    var yVal = 2

    function readdata(x,y) {
        x = xVal;
        y = yVal;
        try {
            var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            excel.Visible = false;
            var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Test1.xls");// alert(excel_file.worksheets.count);
            var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");
            var data = excel_sheet.Cells(x, y).Value;
            //alert(data);
            drawWithexcelValue(data);

            xVal = xVal + 1;

        }

        catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
    }
```

this is the code through which I am reading the excel file.

Comment: Try adding `excel.Quit()` at the end.

Comment: where should i add this in my program ,because i tried it already but it doesn't helped..

Comment: I would add it before the closing `}` of the `readdata` function.

Comment: if i do this then every time the value is incremented then the excel file will be closed ..and FYI i did that ,even in if else condition but it won't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
data = null;
excel_sheet = null;
excel_file.Close();    // important
excel_file = null;
excel.Quit();
excel = null;
```

in this (reverse) order. This is (almost) equivalent to setting these values to `Nothing` in VBA.